# Isomorphism of finite models

Tags: logic, model-theory

> Let $\mathfrak A$ and $\mathfrak B$ are models of finite signature $\sigma$. Prove that $\mathfrak A$ and $\mathfrak B$ are isomorphic, if $\mathfrak A \equiv \mathfrak B$ and $\mathfrak A$ is finite model.

So what I made:

Let $\parallel\mathfrak A \parallel$  $\le$ $\parallel\mathfrak B\parallel$ and $\parallel \mathfrak A \parallel = m$. $ $ $\mathfrak A \equiv \mathfrak B$ so for all axioms $\varphi = (\exists y_1 ... \exists y_m)((y_1 \not = y_2)\wedge ... \wedge (y_{m-1} \not = y_m))$ performed $(\mathfrak A \models \varphi$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathfrak B \models \varphi)$ $\Rightarrow$ $(\parallel\mathfrak A \parallel = \parallel\mathfrak B\parallel)$ $\Rightarrow \exists$  $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a bijection, where $\mathfrak A = <A, \sigma>$ and $\mathfrak B = <B, \sigma>$.

How to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Could you verify my proof?

Let signature $\sigma = <f_1^{S_1},...,f_m^{S_m},P_1^{n_1},...,P_k^{n_k},c_1,...c_l>$ , where superscript is arity of function or relations. I wrote $\varphi = (\exists y_1...\exists y_q)((f_1(y_1,...,y_{S_1}) = y_j)\wedge...\wedge (f_m(y_1,...,y_{S_m}))\wedge(P_1^{n_1}y_1,...,y_{n_1}))\wedge...\wedge(P_k^{n_k}y_1,...,y_{n_k}))\wedge(c_1=y_{t_1})\wedge...\wedge(c_l = y_{t_l})\wedge(y_1 \not= y_2)\wedge...\wedge (y_{q-1} \not= y_q))$

After we signify this sentence in first model so that $\mathfrak A \models \varphi$($\gamma$ - is signification and $\gamma(y_i) = a_i$ , where $a_i \in A$). $\mathfrak A \equiv \mathfrak B \Rightarrow \mathfrak B \models \varphi$ when $\zeta$ ($\zeta$ is signification and $\zeta(y_i) = b_i$). Let $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $f(a_i) = b_i$.Then $f$ is our isomorphism.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to choose you bijection f wisely: Since the signature is finite you can write something like "there are exactly n distinct  elements $y_1, \dots y_n$ such that ..." where dots should be replaced by all possible relations holding between $y_i$'s in one of the structures.

Comment: What relations do you have in mind? Let we had written this condition. What would ensue from this?

Comment: The relations in the signature of your structure. An isomorphism is a bijection preserving these relations.

Comment: I add some ideas upper, can you check it, please?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Wlog assume $\mathfrak{A}$ is a graph $(V, E)$ where $V = \{a_0...a_n\}$. Let $\varphi$ be

$$ \varphi :=
\exists x_0...x_n((\bigwedge_{i \neq j}\lnot (x_i = x_j)) \land (\forall y \bigvee_i y = v_i) \land \bigwedge_{(a_i, a_j) \in E} E(x_i, x_j)) \land \bigwedge_{(a_i, a_j) \not \in E} \lnot E(x_i, x_j)))
$$

Then $\mathfrak{A} \models \varphi$ and since $\mathfrak{A}$ is finite, clearly if $\mathfrak{A} \equiv \mathfrak{B}$ then $\mathfrak{A} \cong \mathfrak{B}$.

Since the signature is finite, the definition of $\varphi$ can be augmented/updated in the obvious way to account for every relation/function/constant, so the initial "wlog" is justified.